# Export source via php-cli without HTML

Tags: php

A example script called "hello.php":

```
<?php
// Hello
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Under linux, we can execute:

php -s hello.php > hello.php

and we can see the next:

```
<code><span style="color: #000000">...
```

How can i obtain the source as the original script, with the comments included, without the HTML added by PHP-CLI?, i have seen the parameter "-w", but the comments and whitespaces are stripped.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you overwriting the script with its output?

Comment: That extra HTML is being added by the `-s` option. That's how it does highlighting, by adding HTML color codes.

Comment: If you just want the source, use `cat hello.php`. Why do you need to run `php`?

Comment: Yes, I know it can be done with the 'cat' command, but I wondered if it could be done with the command of PHP..

Comment: I think not. The `php` command is mainly for **running** PHP scripts. It just has this one special mode that will display the script with highlighting. If you don't want the highlighting, there's no reason to use `php` in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-r` option to run PHP commands, and then have the commands print the contents of the script:

```bash
php -r 'readfile("hello.php");'
```

or more generally:

```bash
php -r 'foreach (array_slice($argv, 1) as $file) { readfile($file); }' hello.php somefile.txt
```

Notice that it will print any file, it doesn't have to be a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

This shell command will accomplish what you're looking for:

```
$ cat hello.php > hello.php
```

Comment: Imagine that you can not use the 'cat' command, only the PHP binary, it would be possible?

Comment: @Jovenzuelo If the cat command is not available and you are running Windows, you should be okay with using the 'more' command using the same syntax as above.

Comment: @Jovenzuelo Or if you really want to do it in PHP you can always write a script for it.